# NumericUpDown for touchscreen application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am modifying a Winform application with touchscreen interface. It has a lot of NumericUpDown controls with large font sizes in GUI. But the each control still has tiny up/down arrow for a finger. Is there any way to make the arrow bigger? Or Any way for the arrows to be aligned column-wise?

Comment: Looks like you might not be able to without increasing your font size further. [This page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winformsdatacontrols/thread/478a3668-9176-412b-a8e3-7f319a9fed94) suggests a possible alternative however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could easily create a composite user control consisting of a numeric up down (with no buttons) and two buttons. This would give you full control over the appearance, and really wouldn't add much complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that's a natural way to do it but it would take some time to replace all existing NumericUpDowns in the code. Anyway, thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Thomas - you could design your user control to be compatible with the built-in control, and just replace the declarations in code. You wouldn't have to do anything in the forms designer.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, touch-screen application. A bit of digging in ILSpy gets you the field that you can set via reflection. Of course comes with the caveat that MS could change the implementation at any time:

```
var field = typeof(NumericUpDown).GetField("defaultButtonsWidth", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
field.SetValue(nudMyNumericUpDown, 30);
```